# Python OpenCV Error(-215) in VideoWriter.write

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to a write a python3-opencv3 code to read the color video and convert it to grayscale and save it back.
(Trying exercises to learn python & opencv)

As I am working in ubuntu, I found out cv2.VideoCapture isColor flag will not work (it works only windows)

---

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')
ret, frame = cap.read()
print('ret =', ret, 'W =', frame.shape[1], 'H =', frame.shape[0], 'channel =', frame.shape[2])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
height, width = gray.shape[:2]
print(height,width)
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
FPS= 20.0
FrameSize=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]) 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video_output.avi', fourcc, FPS, (width,height))

while(ret):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret == False:
        break
    print('ret =', ret, 'W =', frame.shape[1], 'H =', frame.shape[0], 'channel =', frame.shape[2])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Save the video
    out.write(gray) 
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

It is give me this 
error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height*3 in function write

I am guessing, the problem is with framesize and grayscale image conversion but I am not able to figure out ? I have tried different combination of height & widht but none are able execute the program correctly.

Can someone help ?

As requested in the comments:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/Coded/VideoCode/Test3", line 70, in <module>
    out.write(gray) 
cv2.error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1486587069159/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:834: error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height*3 in function write
```

Comment: Can you give the full error trace please?  This will help with debugging.

Comment: An error message without a stacktrace is useless: we cannot see which statement(s) triggered it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/Coded/VideoCode/Test3", line 70, in <module>
    out.write(gray) # It's not work without proper size of frame
cv2.error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1486587069159/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:834: error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height*3 in function write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV error `-215` means "assertion failed". The assertion itself is listed in the message (the phrase "Assertion failed" itself probably should, too; you can open a ticket about this in OpenCV's bug tracker). (Update: [my pull request with this change was accepted on 06.03](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/dc1d9ae97378542bb57a9a9fd7c01d2b49f6de15) and was released in `opencv` `3.4.2`.)

As one can deduce from the assertion, it expects the frame to be a 3-color-channel one. To make a grayscale video, [you need to pass `isColor=False` to `VideoWriter` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html):

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video_output.avi', fourcc, FPS, (width,height), False)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought isColor flag wont work on Ubuntu. However, I was able to save the Video_output but hte video is very distorted. None of the frames came out right ? Any particular reason ? How would you have solved the problem - Reading the video and converting to grayscale video. ?

Comment: @AKASHNIGAM Can't say anything without seeing. My only guess is you might be filling the bitmap in incorrect order. Or this may be JPEG compression artifacts (FFMpeg is known to have very low default quality settings for some codecs).  This is a completely unrelated problem to the one here, so please ask it as another question. SO is one-concern-per-question to stay useful for future readers.

Comment: Sure thanks :) still learning my way around both opencv as well as stackoverflow. Thanks