# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I've done research and found that this issue is caused by a non-existent image, however that isn't the case this time. I checked the shape of the image using np.shape, and it returned a value. Here's my code below

```
def process_with_webcam(self):
    ret, frame = self.vs.read()
    frame = frame[1]
    rospy.loginfo(frame.shape)
    if (frame is not None):
        contours = self.detect_balls(frame)
```

and this where it breaks:

```
def detect_balls(self, frame):
    if frame is None:
        rospy.logerror("Empty frame")

        # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
        # color space
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value returned from np.shape? Does it have three values?

Comment: There seems to be an indentation error, inside `if frame is None:`, you are calling `imutils.resize(frame, width=600)`, which is wrong I guess ?

Comment: You should try to debug, output the image type and number of channels of your frame. Judging from the exception you either do not have the correct image type or failed to load the image in the first place.

Comment: Please, don't post text as images (it's unsearchable, and not accessible), and provide a proper [mcve] to make this question better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python OpenCV Error(-215) in VideoWriter.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976002/python-opencv-error-215-in-videowriter-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit here is the statement `frame = frame[1]`, [because](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) (emphasis mine)

> [Indexing with] An integer, *i*, returns the same values as `i:i+1` except the **dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1**. In particular, a selection tuple with the p-th element an integer (and all other entries :) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1. If N = 1 then the returned object is an array scalar.

Hence, you've turned the 3-dimensional `ndarray` representing a 3-channel BGR image into a 2-dimensional `ndarray`. Due to the way how the Python bindings of OpenCV work, a 2-dimensional `ndarray` is treated as a 1-channel (grayscale) image.

This can be easily demonstrated in the command line interpreter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(4*4*3, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(4,4,3)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a.shape
(4, 4, 3)
>>> a[1]
array([[12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a[1].shape
(4, 3)
```

The solution is simple, use `frame = frame[1:2]` instead.

Continuing with the above demonstration:

```
>>> a[1:2]
array([[[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a[1:2].shape
(1, 4, 3)
```

---

As Ivan Pozdeev mentions in the comment, there are other alternative notations. With that in mind, I'd probably pick

```
frame = frame[[1]]
```

since it's terse, and requires specifying just the index you need.

Comment: Better `a[(1,),:,:]` or (the same) `a[[1],:,:]` or `a[[1]]`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I guess more explicit. However not strictly required since "If the number of objects in the selection tuple is less than N , then : is assumed for any subsequent dimensions." | I do like the third one.